# python and XML: how to place two documents into a single document

Tags: python, xml, dom

Here's my code:

```
def extract_infos(i):
    blabla...
    blabla calculate v...
    dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(v)
    return dom

doc = xml.dom.minidom.Document()
for i in range(1,100):
    dom = extract_infos(i)
    for child in dom.childNodes:
        doc.appendChild(child.cloneNode(True))
```

The two last lines work once then:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./c.py", line 197, in <module>
    doc.appendChild(child.cloneNode(True))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1552, in appendChild
    "two document elements disallowed")
xml.dom.HierarchyRequestErr: two document elements disallowed
```

So my question is: How do I place the two existing documents into a new document (placing the root elements of each into a new, overarching root element).

Comment: @Olivier, my answer does show how you can append a DOM to another one in a fairly "clean" way, but I suppose that you wanted something else. I don't understand the solution you mention in the comment to Lattyware's answer. Is the end result a well-formed XML document, or what is it?

Comment: @Oliver I finally understand your question - you asked for adding one dom to the end of another one, but what you actually wanted was to take two documents and put them both as a part of a new document, which is a different thing. The former isn't possible while producing XML, hence my answer. The latter, on the other hand, is.

Comment: @Lattyware May I ask you to update my question accordingly? I'm sorry for my English, there's room from improvement :/ Thank you again

Comment: I have submitted an edit (that must be peer-reviewed before it becomes live) which I think clarifies what you want. I would state the question as 'How do I place the two existing documents into a new document (placing the root elements of each into a new, overarching root element).'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how XML documents can be appended to a single master root element using minidom.

```
from xml.dom import minidom, getDOMImplementation

XML1 = """
<sub1>
 <foo>BAR1</foo>
</sub1>"""

XML2 = """
<sub2>
 <foo>BAR2</foo>
</sub2>"""

impl = getDOMImplementation()
doc = impl.createDocument(None, "root", None)

for s in [XML1, XML2]:
    elem = minidom.parseString(s).firstChild
    doc.firstChild.appendChild(elem)

print doc.toxml()
```

=>

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><root><sub1>
 <foo>BAR1</foo>
</sub1><sub2>
 <foo>BAR2</foo>
</sub2></root>
```

Since appending `Document` objects doesn't work, `firstChild` is used to get the toplevel `Element`.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was waiting for, `thank you so much`!

Answer (score 1):

The question asked how to **append** one XML document to the other, which means I gave the following answer:

An XML document [must have a single root node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element), so this is not possible while producing valid XML.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I wasn't asking only "why", but "how" too... I still don't know how to append a whole dom to another one. I guess there's something to do with `child.cloneNode(True)` but I don't know how...

Comment: @OlivierPons What I was saying wasn't a why - it was an 'It's impossible'. You cannot append a dom to another one as that would not produce XML. If you truly want to do it, read the contents of the file and append them to the end of the other file as a text operation. This will do what you want, although the result will be useless as it won't be valid XML.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done: transform to XML (`dom.toprettyxml(indent="  ").encode('utf-8')`) then remove the `<xml>` header and concatenate all the stuff like this, then I call `dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(v)`. Works perfectly but from my point of view it's not "clean". Anyway it works. I check your answer as valid even though I could answer myself and give the solution to help the community =)